# How to press the button if the focus is not going to that button using up and down key in monkey runner?

Tags: monkeyrunner

I am on screen 1. There is a button called "Register Now" is there on the screen. If I press any key, the button is not gaining focus. So i can not able to press the button using the keys to go to the subsequent pages. is there any way to select the button by any other way?

Also please let me know that is there any way to swipe through the images on the screen..

Regards,
Chandra